# weinre debugging not working with android-emulator

Tags: android-emulator, weinre

Hello i try to debug my HTML/CSS for Android via an Android-Emulator [android-sdk](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) (width Ubuntu 14.04 Linux).

I followed the install and running [Documentations](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/Running.html).
weinre Server starts successfully.
I get also a successful (intranet) connection between my linux firefox (as client) and an ioS-simulation on mac (as debug-target).

BTW i get access to my local-host sites with android-emulation.

**My Problem is:**
**I cant get a successful client, debug-target connection between my android-emulation and the host.**

here the content of my **weinre.server.properties** file

```
boundHost:    my-local-dns-name
httpPort:     8888
reuseAddr:    true
readTimeout:  1
deathTimeout: 5
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The android simulator runs in a virtual machine running on your desktop/laptop, so that may be causing some issues; perhaps networking-wise there is some additional work to do.  You may have better luck with a weinre server running on the public internet, like this one (that I run): http://weinre.mybluemix.net